# Gauss seidel method not working for specific input

Tags: c

I have done the  programming for gauss-seidel method,which is working for all inputs,except the following equation:

```
    1.876 x1+2.985 x2-11.620 x3=-0.972

    12.214 x1+2.367 x2 +3.672 x3=7.814

    2.412 x1+9.879 x2 +1.564 x3 =4.890
```

When I am running with this input,there is a run time error of "floating point overflow."It is working fine if I am using integer input.My code is as follows:

//GAUSS SEIDEL METHOD

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define e 0.001

void main() {

int i,j,n,count;
double a[10][10],x[10];
double sum,temp,error,big;

printf("Enter the number of equations: ");
scanf("%d",&n) ;
printf("Enter the co-efficients of the equations: \n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n+1;j++) {
          printf("a[%d][%d]= ",i,j);
          scanf("%lf",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        x[i]=0;

    count=1;

    do {
        big=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            sum=0;

            for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if(j!=i) {
                    sum = sum+a[i][j]*x[j];
                }
            }

            temp = (a[i][n]-sum)/a[i][i];
            error = fabs((x[i]-temp)/temp);

            if(error>big) {
                big=error;
            }

            x[i]=temp;
            printf("%d\tx[%d] =%lf",count,i,x[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        count++;

    }while(big>=e);

    printf("\n\nconverges to solution");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("\nx[%d]=%lf",i,x[i]);
    }
    getch();
}//end
```

I cannot find what is to be modified.

Comment: have you tried debugging it? What you see is quite possibly an error caused by division by 0.

Comment: As currently formatted it is impossible to make head or tail of this code. I suggest you tidy it up and run it through a debugger as @IvayloStrandjev suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I think the answer I just gave was nonsense, let me have another think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Though it can be applied to any matrix with non-zero elements on the diagonals, convergence is only guaranteed if the matrix is either diagonally dominant, or symmetric and positive definite.

as it is stated [in the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method).

Your example matrix isn't, so it mustn't come as a too big surprise that the method doesn't converge.

If you reorder the equations, move the first equation last (then the coefficient matrix becomes diagonally dominant), it quickly converges to the approximate solution

```
x[0]=0.500006
x[1]=0.333334
x[2]=0.250001
```

(the exact solution is `(1/2, 1/3, 1/4)`).

What happens is:

1. round:

   - first, `x[0]` gets a negative value (`-0.972/1.876`),
   - next, the sum for the second row becomes negative, and `x[1]` gets a too large value,
   - then, to compensate for the too large value of `x[1]`, `x[2]` gets a negative value too.
2. round:

   - the sum `x[1]*a[0][1] + x[2]*a[0][2]` is positive, since both `x[2]` and `a[0][2]` are negative, and `x[1]` and `a[0][1]` are positive. Thus `x[0]` gets an even smaller negative value than in the first round,
   - then `x[0]*a[1][0] + x[2]*a[1][2]` is negative, and the value of `x[1]` becomes larger to compensate,
   - then the value of `x[2]` becomes a smaller negative value to compensate
3. and further rounds: see round 2.

After some time, you get infinities and NaNs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel Fischer...the detailed answer was really helpful

Comment: @user71067, If it helped you then please do mark it as "accepted" (click the green check mark underneath the score for the answer)